# cannot change background color of div having an image html only in css asp.net

Tags: asp.net, css, html, background-color

Hi 
(little problem im not expert in css)
 i have a div if i change background color it successfully change it but if i add image then it does not change background color of div here is my code

```
 <div class="Cartoon">
 <img src="App_Themes/White/Images/male.png" class="imgMale" />                 
 <div  class="male"><p>In a Nutshell|</p>
 <span>this is some text</span>
 </div>
 </div>

 <style type="text/css">
 .Cartoon
 {
 background-color: yellow;           
 }
 </style>
```

(No jQuery and No Javascript only in css)
you can check heres the url parkingticketpal.com/HowItWorks.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear your `.Cartoon div` since it contains floated elements.

[What methods of ‘clearfix’ can I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best)

Answer (score 0):

You will not see your background color because the Image is already on the background. Try

```
.cartoon{
   background: yellow;
   z-index: 9999
}
```

Then the div is above the image so that you can see the background.

Hint: Try making div bigger than the image.

Answer (score 0):

try this

`

```
<style type="text/css">

{
background-image:url('gradient2.png');
background-repeat:repeat-x;
}
</style>
```

`